# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm executing the following code in node js.

I've a 2d array called graph declared at the top. If I access the property `graph[0].length` in `main()` function and also in `traverseGraph` function it successfully shows the value as 2. But, if I pass 0 as a value to `st` argument of `traverseGraph` function and then try to access `graph[st].length`, I get:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error.

```js
var graph = [[1,2], [2,3]];

main();
function traverseGraph(st)
{
    console.log(graph[0].length);//successfully works
   while(graph[st].length)//fails
    {
        for(var array_el=0; array_el<graph[st].length; array_el++)
        {
            if(graph[st][array_el]){
                var next = graph[st][array_el];
                return traverseGraph(next);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return next;
}
function main(){   
    console.log(graph[0].length); //successfully works
    traverseGraph(0);    
}
```

Comment: Your `for` runs for `0`, `1`, and `2`. It fails when trying to evaluate `graph[2].length`, because `graph[2]` doesn't exist. [**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qo8h09rd/1/) with improved logging. That said, this is a bit of an XY Problem in my opinion. If you tell us the root purpose of the `traverseGraph` function, it can likely be cleaned up quite a bit.

Comment: you need to break the loop when next is going beyond the array length.

Comment: @Shubham This is because graph[st] becomes undefined after two iterations. graph just has 2 elements; you're trying to access graph[2] which is obviously undefined after two iterations. '2' is printed four times - one from main(), three times from each invocation of traverseGraph.

Comment: Thank you guys! I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 0):

```
   while(graph[st] != null && graph[st].length)
    {
        for(var array_el=0; array_el<graph[st].length; array_el++)
        {
            if(graph[st][array_el]){
                var next = graph[st][array_el];
                return traverseGraph(next);
            }
        }
    }
```

Fixed

```
   while(!graph[st] && graph[st].length)
    {
        for(var array_el=0; array_el<graph[st].length; array_el++)
        {
            if(graph[st][array_el]){
                var next = graph[st][array_el];
                return traverseGraph(next);
            }
        }
    }
```

graph[2] or graph[3] doesn't exist

check null

Comment: In js you should always use `===` and `!==`. If you want to check that `graph[st]` is falsy the write `!graph[st]`. To check for not existence you need to test against `undefined` and not `null` (and especially because the error message talks about `undefined` and not about `null`).